# Generate a ID column based on group by as well as the row number

Tags: sql-server, database, group-by, row-number

I am trying to build a database for which I would like the data to be formatted as mentioned in the expected output. Following is the DDL

```sql
CREATE TABLE TEST
(UID int, A1 VARCHAR(10), A2 VARCHAR(10), A3 VARCHAR(10), A4 VARCHAR(10));

INSERT INTO TEST VALUES
(1, 'A1' , 'B1', 'C1', NULL),
(2, 'A1' , 'B1', 'C1', 'D1'),
(3, 'A2' , 'B2', 'C2', 'D1'),
(4, 'A1' , 'B1', 'C1', 'D2'),
(5, 'A2' , 'B2', 'C2', 'D4'),
(6, 'A2' , 'B2', 'C2', 'D6'),
(7, NULL, NULL, 'C3' , NULL),
(8,  NULL, NULL, 'C3' , 'd7');
```

what I'm looking for is to create two ID columns - one based on a Group by of combination of columns A1,A2,A3 and the other for the row_number within those three columns

Expected results:

| UID | A1 | A2 | A3 | A4 | R1ID | R2ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | *Null* | *Null* | C3 | *null* | 1 | 1 |
| 8 | *Null* | *Null* | C3 | d7 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | A1 | B1 | C1 | *null* | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | A1 | B1 | C1 | D1 | 2 | 2 |
| 4 | A1 | B1 | C1 | D2 | 2 | 3 |
| 3 | A2 | B2 | C2 | D1 | 3 | 1 |
| 5 | A2 | B2 | C2 | D4 | 3 | 2 |
| 6 | A2 | B2 | C2 | D6 | 3 | 3 |

I tried

```sql
select *,
       row_number() over (partition by A1,A2,A3 ORDER BY A4) AS R2ID 
FROM TEST;
```

This just gave me the last column of the expected result(R2ID) , but how can I get both the expected columns
(R1ID n R2ID)?

Comment: [`DENSE_RANK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get your first ID by using [`DENSE_RANK()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) and ordering by your "Grouping" columns and, as you have said, your second ID using [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) and partitioning by those same columns. This gives your expected results:

```
SELECT  t.UID,
        t.A1,
        t.A2,
        t.A3,
        t.A4,
        R1ID = DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY t.A1, t.A2, t.A3),
        R2ID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.A1, t.A2, t.A3 ORDER BY t.A4)
FROM    TEST AS t;
```

**[Example on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/M9mR2bX-)**